# C program: __start

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

Can you help me to understand how

```
__start
```

is used in C internally?

Is it the exact replica of the `main` function or is it the entry point to the compiled program?

Just wondering, how its getting used?

Comment: Could you give us some context? Where did you see `__start`?

Comment: It **is** the entry point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) is a good overview of what happens during program startup *before* `main`. In particular, it shows that `__start` is *the actual entry point* to your program from OS viewpoint.

It is the very first address from which the [instruction pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pointer) will start counting in your program.

The code there invokes some C runtime library routines just to do some housekeeping, then call your `main`, and then bring things down and call `exit` with whatever exit code `main` returned.

---

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: C runtime startup diagram]

Comment: Awesome link!!! +1, is it possible to quote the main things in it, in case the site will be down some day, hopefully not.

Comment: In case the article dies some day in future — perhaps the Wayback Machine [might help](https://web.archive.org/web/20170822123701/http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html).

Answer (score 2):

As per C/C++ standard, `main()` is the starting point of a program. If you're using GCC, `_start` function is the entry point of a C program which makes a call to `main()`. The main job of `_start()` function is to perform a few initialization tasks.

```
// $ gcc program_entry.c -nostartfiles
// $ ./a.out
// custom program entry

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void program_entry(void);


void
_start(void)
{ 
    program_entry();
}

void
program_entry(void)
{
    printf("custom program entry\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

If you want, the program entry can also be compiled with `-e` switch in GCC.

```
// $ gcc program_entry.c -e __start
// $ ./a.out
// custom program entr

#include <stdio.h>

void program_entry(void);


void
_start(void)
{ 
    program_entry();
}


void
program_entry(void)
{
    printf("custom program entry\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

_start is a operating system function....which is entry point for any program...as our compiler knows about main(main is not pre defined function it is user defined but all the compiler knows about them) this _start function will call main and from that point our program enters in CPU

Comment: I guess, you must describe !!
Thank you for trying out.